# Use Fragments in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How does one use fragments instead of layouts to give them its on Kotlin file. Using the navigation drawer template in Andriod studio.

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            // Handle the camera action
        }
        R.id.nav_gallery -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_tools -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_share -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_send -> {

        }
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

Does this constructor automatically switch the view based on their name ie nav_gallery I am new to koltin and java so please excuse my ignorance.

**Eg.**
For Example if the Gallery layout how do I show a page that is something other than the content_main.xml that is showing each time I click the navigation bar.

Comment: it's hard to understand what you're going for, could you please clarify your question further?

Comment: @Ahmad i edit my quesiton I just basically want to no how do i navigate pages

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer Use java until you're very comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how you can add a `Fragment` in `kotlin`.fun

```
fun AppCompatActivity.addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int){
    supportFragmentManager.inTransaction { add(frameId, fragment) }
}
```